# "No startup items to display" when running Task Manager as administrator

Tags: windows-10, administrator, task-manager, standard-user

I am trying to disable startup items and some items cannot be disabled when I am running Task Manager as a regular user, when I run it as an Administrator, the startup tab is empty, displaying the message `There are no startup items to display`, even though they were there when running as a regular user. How do I get them to display? Had no such problem with `msconfig` in Windows 7 before.

Comment: Have you tried MSConfig in Windows 10? Right click Start menu, choose Run, then type MSCONFIG

Comment: The Startup tab is only a link to Task Manager since Windows 8, so it just goes back.

Comment: Physic debugging again. Administrators cannot run task manager as a ordinary user. Therefore you are running it as another user. Therefore it shows that user's startup list.

Comment: No, when I run it as a regular user the startup items do show but some cannot be disabled, when I run it as an administrator none of them show up at all.

Comment: Try another MS tool, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns, Autoruns, which gives many more options and *much* greater detail.

Comment: Administrators CANNOT run Task Manager as a limited user. If you were an admin it would demand elevation and refuse to run if not elevated. Therefore you are not using your account to run Task Manager. Therefore it won't show your stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` folders both contain a folder called `Startup`.

Comment: This is an old thread, but anyway, there is no problem there.

Answer (score 1):

Hippity hoppity, I know I'm late as hell, but I got a working solution:

1. Open **Regedit**
2. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`
3. Click on the '**Startup**' key
4. On Value Data, enter: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
5. Check your Task Manager and voila! Your startup apps are back!!

Hope this helps someone in case recreating the Startup folders doesn't work!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).